# Published object not publishing, am I doing it wrong?

Tags: ios, swiftui

My code looks like this:

```
final class MyModelController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var model = MyModel()
}

enum ButtonSelection: Int {
    case left, right
}

final class MyModel {
    var buttonSelection: ButtonSelection?
}
```

I have injected an instance of `MyModelController` as an `@EnvironmentObject` into my SwiftUI views.

When I set `myModelController.model.buttonSelection`, I thought it would update `myModelController.model` and send out an update because it's marked as `@Published`. However, it doesn't. How can I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you make MyModel a struct? Does that fix it?

Comment: @matt It does! However, there's an answer below that uses combine, which also works. Which one is better suited, given that there will be a lot of other changes present within the model?

Comment: If you've no reason to make something a class you should always make it a struct.

Comment: You should always use structs for your Model. [Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_b2oCBmm2Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Published` only detects changes for value types. `MyModel` is a `class`, which is a reference type.

If possible, changing `MyModel` to a `struct` will fix this. However, if this is not possible, see the rest of this answer.

---

You can fix it with Combine. The below code will update `MyModelController` when `model` (now an `ObservableObject`) changes.

```
final class MyModelController: ObservableObject {
    @Published var model = MyModel()

    init() {
        _ = model.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] in
            self?.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}

/* ... */

final class MyModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var buttonSelection: ButtonSelection?
}
```

Comment: Thanks, changing to a struct does work, but this also will. Which is better?

Comment: @Tometoyou A `struct` is preferred. But the `class` solution is if you require to use a class.